# Problema ao enviar imagens para uma pasta com nomes acentuados

Tags: php

Eu estou a enviar uma imagem para uma pasta e a guardar somente a localização (path) da mesma na base de dados. 
Se por exemplo o nome que atribuo a imagem não tiver acentos funciona na perfeição, só que quando tem acentos não funciona. 
Ao guardar na base de dados e ao mostrar no website mostra tudo correto.

Ao guardar na pasta não consigo ir buscar a respectiva imagem porque o caminho (path) é por exemplo **"Produtos/zé"** e aparece assim o nome dentro da pasta **z&A**

Código de envio para a base de dados e para a pasta:

```
    if(isset($_POST['upload']) && isset($_FILES['file-image'])) {
    $filetmp = mysqli_real_escape_string($_FILES["file-image"]["tmp_name"]);
    $filename = mysqli_real_escape_string($dbc, $_FILES["file-image"]["name"]);
    $filetype = mysqli_real_escape_string($dbc, $_FILES["file-image"]["type"]);
    $ProdName = mysqli_real_escape_string($dbc, $_POST['nameProduct']);
    $ProdPrice = mysqli_real_escape_string($dbc, $_POST['productPrice']);
    $ProdDescr = mysqli_real_escape_string($dbc, $_POST['descrProduct']);

    $filepath = "Products/" . $ProdName ;
    $info = getimagesize($filetmp);
    if ($info == FALSE or (empty($ProdName) or empty($ProdPrice) or empty($ProdDescr))) {
        alertError();
    }elseif ($info == FALSE and (empty($ProdName) or empty($ProdPrice) or empty($ProdDescr))) {
        alertError();
    }elseif ($info == TRUE and (empty($ProdName) or empty($ProdPrice) or empty($ProdDescr))) {
        alertError();
    }elseif ($info == TRUE and (!(empty($ProdName) or empty($ProdPrice) or empty($ProdDescr)))) {
        move_uploaded_file($filetmp, $filepath);
        $result = mysqli_query($dbc, "INSERT INTO images (img_name,img_path,img_type) Values('$ProdName','$filepath','$filetype')") or die(errorAdmin());
        $last_id = $dbc->insert_id;
        $insertProduct = mysqli_query($dbc, "INSERT INTO products (name_Product,prod_description,prod_price,img_id)
                                        Values('$ProdName','$ProdDescr','$ProdPrice','$last_id')") or die(errorAdmin());
        mysqli_query($dbc, "SET NAMES 'utf8'") or die(mysqli_error($dbc));
        if ($insertProduct == TRUE and $result == TRUE) {
            ?>
            <script type="text/javascript">
                swal({
                    title: 'Good Job',
                    text: 'Produto Criado Com Sucesso',
                    type: 'success',
                    confirmButtonText: 'Feito'
                });
            </script>
            <?php
        }
    }
    mysqli_close($dbc);
}
```

Comment: Necessitas mesmo que a o nome do ficheiro contenha acentos?

Comment: Sim porque será o nome do produto, logo poderá haver nomes acentuados

Comment: Sugiro que use a função `mysqli_set_charset(connection, charset)` , onde `connection` é seu objeto de conexão e `charset` o tipo de encoding que está usando no banco. Ex.: `mysqli_set_charset($conn, 'utf8')`.

Comment: onde uso essa função? e que eu já tenho no codigo da pagina a função ini_set()

Comment: coloca no php essa função que o @PanterA referiu

Comment: @A.Maia pode colocar logo após a abertura da conexão com o banco. Ou no início desse seu script, a título de teste.

Comment: Desde já obrigado pela ajuda mas não funciona mesmo assim

Comment: @A.Maia acentuação é um ponto um pouco complicado, principalmente se tratando com integrações com banco/linguagem/file system. Uma prática comum em casos como o seu é "limpar" o nome com acentos, substituindo os acentos por ASCII puro. Soluções como [essa](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3542717/how-to-remove-accents-and-turn-letters-into-plain-ascii-characters) devem ajudá-lo nisso.

Comment: @PanterA muito obrigado, fica então sem acentos. Obrigado pela solução

Comment: Normalmente se você tem uma base de dados de produtos, não precisa usar o nome do produto no arquivo. Use o ID da base em vez do nome, que simplifica tudo.

Answer (score 4):

Usar acentuação em nomes de arquivos é um pouco complicado e dificilmente será uma solução portável.

Os sistemas operacionais lidam com codificação de caracteres de formas diferentes.

### Linux

---

O Linux usa binário para os nomes dos arquivos. Isso significa que ele não exige uma codificação específica para salvar o nome do arquivo. Por exemplo se criarmos dois arquivos com codificações diferentes em seus nomes, mas que são equivalentes (falaremos mais sobre isso):

```
$ echo "foo" > $'z\xc3\xa9.txt'
$ echo "bar" > $'ze\xcc\x81.txt'
```

Ao executarmos o comando `ls`, teremos o seguinte output:

```
$ ls 
zé.txt zé.txt
```

Isso significa que o programa que usar o filesystem precisa se preocupar minuciosamente com a codificação e normalização de caracteres, pois se há mais de um arquivo com o mesmo nome, mas com normalizações diferentes, qual arquivo o programa deve considerar o correto? Fora as questões de segurança.

### OSX

---

O OSX já utiliza o UTF-16 para codificar os nomes dos arquivos. Isso é feito de forma transparente para o usuário. Ou seja, se seu programa salvar o nome do arquivo utilizando UTF-8, o OSX vai traduzi-lo para UTF-16.

Outro ponto a ser considerado quando usar o OSX é a forma como ele normaliza os caracteres. A especificação Unicode define algo chamado de [equivalência e normalização](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unicode_equivalence). Esse conceito define como a combinação de caracteres é feita nos diferentes tipos de normalizações (NFD, NFC, NFKD, NFKC) para um mesmo caracter. Para ilustrar esse conceito, basta salvarmos um arquivo com a sequência correta em UTF-8 do caracter é (`\xC3\xA9`):

```
<?php
file_put_contents("z\xC3\xA9.txt","xyz");
?>
```

E checarmos o que realmente foi gravado:

```
<?php
list($file) = glob('z*');
echo urlencode($file) . "\n";
?>
```

Teremos o seguinte output:

```
ze%CC%81.txt
```

O OSX gravou `e0xCC81` em vez de `0xCCA9`. Isso nos mostra que o OSX usa uma normalização que utiliza três bytes, o `e` e mais dois bytes que combinados resultam no acento agudo. Esses três bytes juntos formam a letra `é`.

### Windows

---

O Windows também usa UTF-16 (usando NTFS), com o comportamento semelhante ao OSX, no que tange a tradução transparente dos caracteres. Em relação à normalização, ele se comporta diferente do OSX, se rodarmos o mesmo código que rodamos no OSX veremos os caracteres corretos no output.

### Conclusão

---

Já temos aqui duas formas equivalentes de escrever a mesma letra em Unicode. Temos mais duas, que fogem do escopo aqui. O fato é que se realmente quiser trabalhar com acentos em nome de arquivos, vai precisar de alguns cuidados e provavelmente usar um intermediador para salvar esses arquivos.

A extensão [intl](http://php.net/manual/en/book.intl.php) do PHP oferece uma classe chamada [Normalizer](http://php.net/manual/en/class.normalizer.php) que permite que você controle a normalização dos caracteres. Ela é uma opção interessante caso queira intermediar essas codificações.

Minha sugestão é que traduza os caracteres acentuados para ASCII puro sempre que puder.

Comment: Obrigado pela ajuda

Comment: +1 boa a resposta, pena que é para uma pergunta que deveria ser solucionada de outra forma (merecia mais visibilidade a resposta). Todo mundo esquece da normalização do UTF-8, que é extremamente chata e complexa. Qualquer aplicativo pequeno tem que ser inflado com tabelas gigantescas para ficar portátil. Recentemente expliquei para um conhecido que Á e Á são strings completamente diferentes (as strings não são normalizadas aqui atualmente), mas ele só entendeu quando copiou e colou num editor de código não-unicode.

Comment: @Bacco, Obrigado. Realmente não achei que a resposta seria a solução escolhida para a pergunta, fica mais como uma alternativa. Mas como comentei na pergunta que a melhor opção era optar por não usar acentos em nomes de arquivos, achei melhor explicar o porquê. Já que em um comentário não teria espaço suficiente pra discorrer sobre o assunto, resolvi colocar como resposta.